Error creating broker listeners from PLAINTEXT
I'm new to debezium and having trouble getting it setup in minikube (kubernetes later). I followed the tutorial to get it running with docker compose, but get errors in minikube. I am missing something in the configuration for kafka, but am unsure what it is. Any help?
Tutorial: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/tutorial.html
Error:
WARNING: Using default NODE_ID=1, which is valid only for non-clustered installations.
Starting in ZooKeeper mode using NODE_ID=1.
Using ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
Using configuration config/server.properties.
Using KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://10.244.0.45:tcp://10.109.182.14:9092 and KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://10.244.0.45:9092
2024-09-18 01:49:59,213 - INFO  [main:Log4jControllerRegistration$@31] - Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
2024-09-18 01:49:59,698 - INFO  [main:X509Util@78] - Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2024-09-18 01:49:59,704 - ERROR [main:MarkerIgnoringBase@159] - Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://10.244.0.45:tcp://10.109.182.14:9092': No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT://10.244.0.45:TCP
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:243)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.listeners(KafkaConfig.scala:2177)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1845)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1639)
    at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:71)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:90)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT://10.244.0.45:TCP
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.$anonfun$createEndPoint$2(EndPoint.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.getOrElse(Map.scala:548)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.securityProtocol$1(EndPoint.scala:49)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:57)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.$anonfun$listenerListToEndPoints$10(CoreUtils.scala:240)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:35)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:240)
    ... 6 more

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: zookeeper
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: client
          port: 2181
          targetPort: 2181
        - name: follower
          port: 2888
          targetPort: 2888
        - name: election
          port: 3888
          targetPort: 3888
      selector:
        app: zookeeper
    
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: zookeeper
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: zookeeper
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: zookeeper
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: zookeeper
              image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:2.7.2.Final
              ports:
                - containerPort: 2181
                - containerPort: 2888
                - containerPort: 3888
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: kafka
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 9092
          targetPort: 9092
      selector:
        app: kafka
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: kafka
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: kafka
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: kafka
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: kafka
              image: quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.7.2.Final
              ports:
                - containerPort: 9092
              env:
                - name: ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
                  value: zookeeper:2181
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: postgres
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 5432
          targetPort: 5432
      selector:
        app: postgres
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: postgres
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: postgres
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: postgres
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: postgres
              image: quay.io/debezium/example-postgres:2.7.2.Final
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5432
              env:
                - name: POSTGRES_USER
                  value: postgres
                - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                  value: postgres
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: connect
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 8083
          targetPort: 8083
      selector:
        app: connect
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: connect
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: connect
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: connect
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: connect
              image: quay.io/debezium/connect:2.7.2.Final
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8083
              env:
                - name: BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
                  value: kafka:9092
                - name: GROUP_ID
                  value: "1"
                - name: CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC
                  value: my_connect_configs
                - name: OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC
                  value: my_connect_offsets
                - name: STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC
                  value: my_connect_statuses



Please use Strimzi rather than writing your own resources. It'll deploy Kafka correctly

Using Strimzi and properly configuring the kafka broker got rid of the problem. Thx @OneCricketeer.

Check your listener.security.protocol.map config, for example
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT


I tried adding this config however still could not get it to startup properly, with similar errors popping up. Thx @jinzuchi.
